# Open in new window to add print page functionality

Tags: javascript, .net, html, css, printing

I want to add print page functionality to my website. Current behavior : There is a print icon in footer, when I click on print icon it directly opens up printer dialog box. Instead of this, new expected behavior is: when i click on Print icon -> It opens the contents of current page in a new window with separate header and footer. a new "Print" button should be present in the header. When i click on "Print" button present in header, Print dialog box should open up.

As of now i am able to open a new window on click on Print icon of actual page using following code :

```
var printLinks = {};

printLinks.init = function() {
     $('body').on('click', '.js-print-link', function(e) {
          myWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'resizable,scrollbars,status');
          myWin.document.write("<p>Test</p>");
          myWin.document.close();
          myWin.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
     });
};
```

But the content of current page is not being displayed in new window. What should i write in document.write() method instead of Test?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function CallPrint(strid1) {
            var prtContent1 = document.getElementById(strid1);
            var prtContent2 = document.getElementById(strid2);
            <%--  var prtContent1 = document.getElementById("<%=UserDetails1.ClientID %>");
            var prtContent2 = document.getElementById("<%=UserDetails2.ClientID %>");--%>
       <%--     document.getElementById('<%=UserDetails1.ClientID%>');--%>
          <%--  var prtContent1 = document.getElementById('<%=MasterPage2.FindControl("UserDetails1").ClientID %>');
            var prtContent2 = document.getElementById('<%=MasterPage2.FindControl("UserDetails2").ClientID %>');
            var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=10,top=10,width="450",height="250",toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,status=1');

            //WinPrint.document.write("<html><div>UserDetails1</div><body>");
            //WinPrint.document.write("<html><body>");
            WinPrint.document.write(prtContent1.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.write(prtContent2.innerHTML);
            //WinPrint.document.write("</body></html>");
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();

            return false;
        }
    </script>


 <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt" onclick="return CallPrint('UserDetails');" value=" Peerint ">
```

userdeatils --> print div id

Comment: some explanation with your answer will be useful

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to print the content of the page with different header and footer, I suggest you look at using @media query in your css to show and hide elements on Print.   As you see below, the .header_print and .footer_print will remain hidden until you do a Ctrl+P or window.print();
With this approach, you never have to create another window for printing.

```
@media print {
.header, .footer {
    display:none;
}
.header_print, .footer_print {
    display: block;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, the ultimate goal is not so. If you browse through http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzminus-zum-trotz-metro-bleibt-bei-gewinnprognose/12467366.html On the left hand side u'll see an image named Media Markt and to its left there are three icons. If you hover on second icon, it says "drucken" . Click on this icon, a new window opens up with some content and "drucken" button in the header. After clicking on this button, print dialog box opens up. I want to implement similar functionality.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is actually different from what is done by handelsblatt.  They use server-side call to return printable page.  To prove that, just navigate to this link (http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzminus-zum-trotz-metro-bleibt-bei-gewinnprognose/v_detail_tab_print/12467366.html).  All they really seem to do is just window.open('http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzminus-zum-trotz-metro-bleibt-bei-gewinnprognose/v_detail_tab_print/12467366.html')

Comment: I agree. but how do they create such printable page (http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzminus-zum-trotz-metro-bleibt-bei-gewinnprognose/v_detail_tab_print/12467366.html) from actual page (http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/handel-konsumgueter/umsatzminus-zum-trotz-metro-bleibt-bei-gewinnprognose/12467366.html) is my concern and also the place where i am stuck currently

Comment: I think you are looking at it the wrong way.  You don't create a printable page from the actual page, you need to create another page on your website that has reduced amount of content good enough for printing which pulls data from server much like the 'actual' page does it.